# Bad BSON Document: illegal CString with Node MongoDB driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm receiving:

`[Error: Bad BSON Document: illegal CString]`

When using the Node MongoDB driver while iterating over one of my collections with `Cursor.each`. It seems to make some of my documents disappear, and not found in the collection, even though they were individually accessible when I look for them using `Collection.findOne()`.

Does this mean that my data is corrupted in some way?

Comment: The driver is having trouble deserializing a string. Glancing at the [code](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/ext/bson.cc), it might be a missing null byte at the end of the string. Can you access the data? What happens if you query the bad document in the shell? You could also try using [validate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.validate/) to check for problems with the data.

Comment: I'm having difficulty determining which document is the bad document that's causing this error. All the Node MongoDB driver is giving me is an error, with no ObjectID I can use to query for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @wdberkeley for all the help in the above comment, which helped me to track down my problem.

It turns out that I did have a single corrupted document in my collection, which was inserted during an unclean shutdown of Mongo. I was unaware how that document would affect the rest of my queries though.

When you perform a `collection.find()`, and then start iterating with the cursor over the collection, the cursor will stop and be unable to go any further if it encounters an error, such as with `[Error: Bad BSON Document: illegal CString]`.

This happens with both `cursor.forEach` or `cursor.nextObject`. Thus, I was unable to access any of the documents that came after the error in the collection, even though I was able to access those documents individually with `collection.findOne`.

The only solution in this scenario for me was to run `db.repairDatabase`, which removed the corrupted documents, and solved the problem for me.